# Which React component library can I use in Next.js 13.1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am relatively new to Next.js. Trying out version `13.1` and the new `app` directory.

Is it possible to do so? Without losing the new benefits of server controls?

I see the following error:

```
You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this. i am using https://ui.shadcn.com/

Answer (score 0):

The *useState* hook only runs on the client. In case your component uses it consider adding the *[“use client”](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#convention)* directive at the top of the component file. This will pre-render your markup on the server and run the ‘useState’ hook after the rehydration.