# Sanity Preview Mode not intiating

Tags: next.js, sanity

I used sanity with nextjs-13 to build a blog, and I now want to add the live-preview mode to it, but every time I hit the /api/preview to enable the preview mode, I get thrown this error:

TypeError: useReducer only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99vXw.png)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)

Comment: Not quite. I have added the "use client" market at the top of the page but the error still persists. -- @yousoumar