# How can I avoid errors when using new Nextjs 13 app with MUI?

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js13

when I try to use MUI with new NextJS 13 app functionality I get next error:

```
You're importing a component that needs useRef. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
```

I avoided it once by separating all mui jsx in separate component but the problem is that I'm gonna get this error everywhere in my app. For example I need to write jsx in my layout.tsx or page.tsx which are server components by default. Can I actually use experimentall app with MUI without this kind of problems now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)