# NextJS component is failing to compile locally when using useState with error "it only works in a Client component"

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, tailwind-css

[This is the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hZzH.png)

The directories are correct, but i'm experiencing some difficulties with this, basically i'm using css code as well.

The page is not showing anything. Just that and when i run:

```
npm run dev
```

it shows this:

[What i see!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHDVp.png)

Comment: From what I understant you're using Nextjs 13 ? To use state you need to add 'use client' at the first line of your file. That's what the error says. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#convention

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `useState` in a component that your app is treating as a server component.

To fix this, in your `src/app/page.tsx` put this as the first line in your file:

```
"use client"
```

This will tell next that this is meant to be a client component so you can now safely make use of `useState`.