# TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I created a brand new Next.js application that uses the `app` folder. I then installed Materiel UI and started using the [example given on the doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/usage/). But I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.

Here is the example from the doc in my code:

```js
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm expecting to have the button displayed on my page. I understand that adding `"use client"` at the top will fix the error, but I want my page to be rendred on the server.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Obviously, the button you are importing is using client-side hooks, `createContext` in this case. For this to work, you need to add `"use client"` at the top of the file. But it would mean the page becomes a [Client Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components), and no longer a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components).

If that bothers you, you could, for example, create a `lib` folder at the same level as `app` in which you add a `mui.js` file, like so:

```js
// lib/mui.js

"use client";

export * from "@mui/material";
```

And you import it from there (this way, other parts of the page are still Server Components):

```js
// app/page.js

import { Button } from "../lib/mui";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Side note, you may get a similar error while setting up a context. It means you are trying to set it up in a Server Component. The [guideline](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#context) is to add it in its own "use client" marked file:

```
// app/theme-provider.tsx

"use client";

import { createContext } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext("");

export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And import it from there:

```
// app/layout.js

import ThemeProvider from './theme-provider';
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

For an even more elaborate answer, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import your own `ThemeProvider`, not the `ThemeProvider` from `next-themes`

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@/components/theme-provider'
```

Comment: this was it for me. Did the wrong import when setting it up for shadcn. Got `TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

There are some tweeks you have to do to get MUI to play nicely with SSR: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-next-app-router-ts .

Note: Even if you configure things properly, the Button can be rendered on server-side but you cannot assign onClick handler (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

`usePathname` is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's pathname.

```
'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return <p>Current pathname: {pathname}</p>
}
```