# What are the server and client-side components in the new app router in Next.js, and how can they be identified?

Tags: next.js

What are the server and client-side components in the new app router in Next.js, and how can they be identified?
What is the use case of the server and client-side components in the new app router in Next.js?

Comment: Checkout [you're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp). While the questions are different, the answer might help you.