# Integrating RecoilRoot in Next.js using Next.js 13 (App router approach) structure

Tags: next.js, recoiljs

I'm building a Next.js project where I've chosen to use Recoil for state management. I've organized my project following the `src/app/pages.tsx` (app router approach) structure in next.js 13 for routing instead of using the default `_app.tsx` approach. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to wrap my entire app with the `RecoilRoot` provider using this structure.

Here's a glimpse of my directory structure:

```
my-nextjs-project/
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │   ├── components/
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── global.css
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── ...other files
├── ...
```

As I'm not using the `_app.tsx`, I'm wondering how I can still wrap my entire app with the `RecoilRoot` provider to make the Recoil state available throughout my application. Is there a different file I need to modify or any alternative approach I should consider in this situation?

I'd appreciate any insights, code examples, or guidance on how to achieve this integration with the App router structure in Next.js. Thank you in advance for your help!

I've been exploring the available documentation for both Next.js and Recoil, but most of the examples I've come across use the default `_app.tsx` approach for wrapping the app in `RecoilRoot`. Since I'm following the App router structure for routing, I haven't been able to directly adapt those examples to my project.

I've considered manually wrapping each individual page component with RecoilRoot in Next.js 13, but this seems repetitive and not in line with best practices.

My expectation is to find a way to wrap the entire app with `RecoilRoot` without directly using the `_app.tsx` file, making the Recoil state accessible across all pages and components.

Answer (score 2):

As they say on [Upgrade Guide](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide) page, `pages/_app.js` and `pages/_document.js` have been replaced by `app/layout.js`.

That has been said, find below an example of setting up Recoil simulating a todo list:

```js
// app/recoilContextProvider.tsx

"use client";

import { RecoilRoot, atom } from "recoil";
export const todoListState = atom({
  key: "TodoList",
  default: [],
});

export default function RecoidContextProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <RecoilRoot>{children}</RecoilRoot>;
}
```

```js
// app/layout.tsx

import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import RecoidContextProvider from "./recoilContextProvider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <RecoidContextProvider>{children}</RecoidContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```js
"use client";

import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { todoListState } from "./recoilContextProvider";

export default function TodoList() {
  const todoList = useRecoilValue(todoListState);
  console.log(todoList);
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't we use `useRecoilValue` with server side components or page ?

Comment: No, you cannot. Server components are not meant to handle client interactivities (onClicks, hooks...)

Comment: No, you cannot. [Server components are not meant to handle client interactivities (onClicks, hooks...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)

Comment: this solution dont work with next v.13/v.14. values in recoil gone lost after router.push()