# How to share store data between client and server components in next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, next.js13

I am using redux toolkit for state management in next.js 13 project. I am using following 2 functions for fetching and updating data from store like this.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
export default function Posts() {
  const posts = useSelector((state: any) => state.posts);
  // more code...
}
```

I have client components and server components in my project. Since these hooks `useSelector` is not working in server components. I have to write `use client` at top of all components where ever I want to fetch redux store data using `useSelector` hook.

I even had to wrape my provider as client component as show below:

```
'use client'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";

function Providers({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}

export default Providers;
```

store.ts file

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postsSlice from "./slices/postsSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        posts: postsSlice
    }
})
```

Any suggestion or guideline how I can share data between client and server components here? I don't want to write 'use client' at top of each file.

Comment: What do you mean by charing? Like fetching data in a server component and using it in client component with your Redux store?

Comment: This answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp) covers the topic of sharing data between client and server components.