still giving error after using the use client on top in next.js component
× You're importing a component that needs useRouter. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
"use client ";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'


export const NavBar = () => {
const router = useRouter()

return (
    <div className='fixed inset-x-0 top-0 h-20 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-between px-10'>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={() => router.push('/api/auth/signin')}
                className='bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md'>
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
)}

as you can see i using the 'use client' on top of file but still its giving me error, that i can not use useRouter in client component and its showing mark the parent component as 'use client', then my whole page will become client component if i mark it.
then what the point to use the next.js if my whole page is client component. help me to solve it without making parent component as client component.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74965849/519413

I think there is a blank after use client
the component is still server component
"use client ";
↓
"use client";
